# Exercício em C retorna valor errado

Tags: c

estou tentando fazer um exercício em C que não gera nenhum erro de sintaxe,já procurei e não consigo achar o erro,ele simplesmente lê ou retorna os valores errados.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {



        int codigo,quantidade;
        float precototal;
        char especificacao[] = "";
        printf("Escreva o codigo do produto:");
        scanf("%d",&codigo);
            printf("Escreva a quantidade do produto:");
        scanf("%d",&quantidade);

        switch(codigo)
        {
        case 100:
        strcpy(especificacao, "Cachorro Quente"); 
         printf("%d",quantidade);
        precototal = 1.20 * quantidade;

        printf("Produto:%s,Quantidade:%d,preco unitario:%f,preco total:%f",especificacao,quantidade,1.20,precototal);

        break;
        case 101:

        break;
        case 102:

        break;
        case 103:

        break;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

o valor que é retornado é isso:
[image: execução]

Comment: Tem como melhorar sua pergunta? Não da pra saber o que você quer.

Comment: Ao inserir o codigo e quantidade do produto,é retornado valores errados,como mostra a imagem,o preco total e a quantidade saem errados.

Comment: Quais foram os dados de entrada? Poderia colocar a saida por escrito?

Comment: foram 100 e 1,porém já foi resolvido de acordo com a resposta abaixo,obrigado!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tente identar o seu codigo corretamenta

eu inicializei a sua `string` `char especificacao[]` com um tamanho `[30]` e aqui funcionou veja como ficou o codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int codigo,quantidade;
    float precototal;
    char especificacao[30];
    printf("Escreva o codigo do produto:");
    scanf("%d",&codigo);
    printf("Escreva a quantidade do produto:");
    scanf("%d",&quantidade);

    switch(codigo)
    {
    case 100:
    strcpy(especificacao, "Cachorro Quente");
    printf("%d",quantidade);
    precototal = 1.20 * quantidade;
    printf("Produto:%s,Quantidade:%d,preco unitario:%f,preco total:%f",especificacao,quantidade,1.20,precototal);
    break;
    case 101:

    break;
    case 102:

    break;
    case 103:

    break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

você também poderia inicializar a sua `string` `especificacao` como ponteiro de `char` `char *especificacao;` também iria funcionar emfim o erro estava na inicialização desta variavel você não pode inicializar um `vetor` apontando pra `""` `0` no caso.

Comment: Realmente funcionou!
Saberia me explicar o por que de não poder colocar só especificacao[] ? sem definir um tamanho ?
Desde já obrigado!

Comment: poder pode mas voce inicializou o seu vetor no casso array com `""` no caso `0` ou `NULL` eu anda não sei realmente o por que mas com os testes que vim fazendo se voce tentar iniciar um vetor\string assim `char vs[0];` fica impossivel de se trabalhar com essa variavel emfim espero ter ajuda ^^

Answer (score 1):

Nosso amigo @Assanges está correto. O problema é a linha que contém a declaração

```
char especificacao[] = "";
```

O que acontece é que vc não está declarando o **tamanho da área na memória** reservada para guardar uma `String`, isto é, quantos bytes pretende usar para guardá-la. Por algum motivo a função `strcpy` retorna corretamente a palavra `"Cachorro Quente"` para dentro de `especificacao`.

Porém, como não há uma quantidade de memória exata reservada, possivelmente o retorno da função acaba sobrescrevendo área reservada para alguma de suas outras variáveis e por isso o resultado é incorreto.

---

A maneira correta de declarar variáveis do tipo String ,que é um ponteiro para caractere, é como o Assanges disse

```
char especificacao[30];
```

Aqui ele separa 30 bytes na memória para guardar caracteres. Note que vc poderá guardar apenas **29** caractares, pois o caracter `\0` denota o final da string e é indispensável.

---

Este problema pode ser melhor visto caso você tente ler do console alguma `string` de tamanho arbitrário para dentro da variável sem tamanho declarado, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
char especificacao[] = "";
        scanf("%s",&especificacao); 
    printf("Produto: %s ",especificacao);
```

Dependendo do tamanho da sua entrada, o programa pode escrever sua entrada, ou pode dar falha de segmentação.

Comment: Muito boa a explicação,obrigado!